# Rails redirect_to in update goes back to show though asked to go back to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, routes

**UPDATE** 
I added the suggestion in comment but I still have an issue

I have a quote object (standard MVC:model,DB,controller and view), and in the show view, I have an update button that sends (through AJAX) a put method to update the quote. In the controller update, I have a redirect to index(/quotes) but just after redirecting me to the index it redirects to the show view and this at each time.
Here is the function that sends the AJAX request in the show view:

```
function quoteUpdate(id){
var url_up="/quotes/"+id
var title=document.getElementById("qtitle").value;
var total=parseInt(document.getElementById("amount_total").innerHTML);
var list=[];

var request=$.ajax({
    url: url_up,
    type: "PUT",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    data: {q_update: {
             title: title, 
             total: total,
             list: list }}
 });

request.done(doAjaxCall(id));
}

function doAjaxCall(id) {
   $.ajaxSetup({complete: onRequestCompleted});
   var id=id;
   $.ajax({
        url: "/quotes#index",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        data: {id: id }
        });

}
```

Here is the HTML that launches the function:

```
<button onclick="quoteUpdate(<%= @quote.id %>)">Sauve et retour</button>
```

Here is the update method in the controller with the redirect at the end

```
def update
    title=params['q_update']['title']
    total=params['q_update']['total']
    list=params['q_update']['list']
    quote_p={:title=>title,:total=>total,:list=>list}
    @quote.update(quote_p)
    redirect_to quotes_path
end
```

My rake routes for quotes is:

```
  GET    /quotes(.:format)           quotes#index
```

And in the log I can see that the update is successful then, I see the redirect call done from the AJAX doAjaxCall:

```
Started GET "/quotes?id=14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 10:26:43 -0700
Processing by QuotesController#index as */*
Parameters: {"id"=>"14"}
Quote Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "quotes".* FROM "quotes"
Rendered quotes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 139.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

The index method is classic:

```
def index
@quotes = Quote.all
end
```

But after this, there is a weird PUT call:

```
Started PUT "/quotes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 10:26:43 -0700
```

that comes from :

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/quotes 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4
 m.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:4
 m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
 quoteUpdate 14:1316
 onclick
```

Why is this PUT call performed by jquery? How can I get rid of it without deleting jquery.min?
Thank you for your help and support

Comment: from where you are calling the ajax also paste code

Comment: I have added the HTML that calls the function in js in which there is the ajax code. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was the following:
I do an AJAX PUT call to update my model in rails and then after the request success I use the window.location.replace(url) that allows to change the page.

```
request.done(doAjaxCall());

function doAjaxCall() {
window.location.replace("/quotes")
}
```

Thanks for help allenwei

Answer (score 0):

jquery ajax can not handle redirect by default, you need handle it your self

```
function doAjaxCall() {
   $.ajaxSetup({complete: onRequestCompleted});
   $.get(yourUrl,yourData,yourCallback);
}


function onRequestCompleted(xhr,textStatus) {
   if (xhr.status == 302) {
      location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It helped but I still have an issue: a weird PUT call... I updated my post with the information. Do you have any idea? Thanks for your help

Comment: I found out that the PUT call is initiated by the jquery file.